# Hive Joins(Query to find out specific part of table)

Tags: join, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

Hi Everyone I am new to Hive Join.

I just want to know the query to find out specific value in the given image below.(Green Part)

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsjhA.png)

I have two table A and B,I want to find out the value in Table B which is not matching with the values in Table A.

(2)And separate value in Table A which is not matching with Table B.